# Warning! The 'flutter' tool you are currently running is from a different Flutter repository than the one last used by this package

Tags: flutter

Everytime i try to build an apk or appbundle, this error comes up. please help.

Warning! The 'flutter' tool you are currently running is from a different Flutter repository than the one last used by this package. The repository from which the 'flutter' tool is currently executing will be u
sed instead.
running Flutter tool: C:\Users\MOMO\Mygit\flutter
previous reference : C:\flutter
This can happen when you have multiple copies of flutter installed. Please check your system path to verify that you are running the expected version (run 'flutter --version' to see which flutter is on your pat
h).

Compiler message:
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/layer.dart:1580:36: Error: 'ImageFilterEngineLayer' isn't a type.
oldLayer: _engineLayer as ui.ImageFilterEngineLayer,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/layer.dart:1578:27: Error: The method 'pushImageFilter' isn't defined for the class 'SceneBuilder'.

'SceneBuilder' is from 'dart:ui'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'pushImageFilter'.
engineLayer = builder.pushImageFilter(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script 'C:\Users\MOMO\Mygit\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

Process 'command 'C:\Users\MOMO\Mygit\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done 15.7s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

#### Thats my flutter doctor -v

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.778], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at C:\Users\MOMO\Mygit\flutter
• Framework revision f139b11 (4 weeks ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
• Engine revision af51afceb8
• Dart version 2.7.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\MOMO\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
• Java binary at: D:\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
• Android Studio at D:\Android\Android Studio1
• Flutter plugin version 45.0.1
• Dart plugin version 192.7761
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.3)
• IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1
• Flutter plugin version 45.0.2
• Dart plugin version 193.5731

[!] Connected device
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.